# JavaScript function that flips brackets direction

Tags: javascript, strings, regex, typescript

I have these strings:

```
)hello(
this has ]some text[
flip }any{ brackets
even with )))]multiple[((( brackets
```

As you can see, the brackets are all in the wrong direction.

I have a function called `flipBracketsDirection()` to handle each scenario. Here is an example of input and output of the above strings:

```
flipBracketsDirection(')hello(');
// should return:  (hello)

flipBracketsDirection('this has ]some text[');
// should return:  this has [some text]

flipBracketsDirection('flip }any{ brackets');
// should return:  flip {any} brackets

flipBracketsDirection('even with )))]multiple[((( brackets');
// should return:  even with ((([multiple]))) brackets
```

**Note**: The direction is flipped at **all** times. So this is fine too:

```
flipBracketsDirection('flip (it) anyway');
// should return:  flip )it( anyway
```

Here is my solution.

```
function flipBracketsDirection(str: string) {
  return str
    // flip () brackets
    .replace(/\(/g, 'tempBracket').replace(/\)/g, '(').replace(/tempBracket/g, ')')

    // flip [] brackets
    .replace(/\[/g, 'tempBracket').replace(/\]/g, '[').replace(/tempBracket/g, ']')

    // flip {} brackets
    .replace(/\{/g, 'tempBracket').replace(/\}/g, '{').replace(/tempBracket/g, '}')
    ;
}
```

Is this the best way to create this function?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your function seems to work fine, but you can condense it a bit by search for all bracket types in one regex replace with the following pattern:

```
/[\(\)\[\]\{\}]/g
```

and then use the `replace` function that takes a replace function as argument:

```
const brs = "()({}{[][";
function flipBracketsDirection(str) {
  return str.replace(/[\(\)\[\]\{\}]/g, br => brs[brs.indexOf(br) + 1]);
}
```

`brs` holds all the replaceable brackets with the opening brackets twice, so `brs[brs.indexOf(')') + 1]` finds `'('` as the next char in `brs`;

You could also let `brs` be an object like:

```
const brs =
{
  "(": ')',
  ")": '(',
  "{": '}',
  "}": '{',
  "[": ']',
  "]": '[',
};
```

and then cquery it as:

```
function flipBracketsDirection(str) {
  return str.replace(/[\(\)\[\]\{\}]/g, br => brs[br]);
}
```

Your version actually query the string nine times, where the above only iterates it once.

As an alternative to the 'sophisticated' `brs` dictionary-solution, you could just create a function with a switch statement:

```
function swapBracket(br) {
  switch (br) {
    case '(': return ')';
    case ')': return '(';
    case '{': return '}';
    case '}': return '{';
    case '[': return ']';
    case ']': return '[';
  }
}
```

And call that instead, this way:

```
function flipBracketsDirection(str: string) {
  return str.replace(/[\(\)\[\]\{\}]/g, swapBracket);
}

flipBracketsDirection('}hello{');
// will return {hello}
```

---

Your tests cases could also be simplified, so it is easier to maintain - for instance like:

```
  let strs = [
    ')hello(',
    'this has ]some text[',
    'flip }any{ brackets',
    'even with )))]multiple[((( brackets'
  ];

  for (let s of strs) {
    let t = flipBracketsDirection(s);
    console.log(t);
    console.log(flipBracketsDirection(t));
    console.log("");
  }
```

---

Both the above suggestions should conform to the DRY principle.

Comment: What's you're opinion on `brs = '(){}[]'`, `brs[brs.indexOf(br) ^ 1]`?

Comment: Too clever for me @Peilonrayz. Sure, it works, but coming back to that in a month..?

Comment: @Gerrit0 I've never heard anyone say xor is 'too clever' before.

Comment: @Peilonrayz: That's indeed clever, I din't think in that direction - I thought my solution was clever. +1 from me :-)

Comment: What wonderful ways to solve this! I think all of you are clever. What does ^ do? I couldn't find anything on google

Comment: @Elron [bitwise XOR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_XOR)

Comment: @Peilonrayz: For what it's worth, I find your version much clearer, and less error-prone. The next dev might not notice that the brackets need to be written 3 times otherwise, and would simply add `brs = "<>()({}{[]["`.

Comment: @EricDuminil I was really confused by the `+ 1` at first. But meh you can't win them all ;)

Answer (score 8):

It may seem unlikely but it is not impossible for an input string to contain `tempBracket` so a solution that doesn't involve adding and replacing that string would be ideal.

```js
function flipBracketsDirection(str) {
  return str
    // flip () brackets
    .replace(/\(/g, 'tempBracket').replace(/\)/g, '(').replace(/tempBracket/g, ')')

    // flip [] brackets
    .replace(/\[/g, 'tempBracket').replace(/\]/g, '[').replace(/tempBracket/g, ']')

    // flip {} brackets
    .replace(/\{/g, 'tempBracket').replace(/\}/g, '{').replace(/tempBracket/g, '}')
    ;
}
console.log(flipBracketsDirection(')will tempBracket get replaced?('))
```

The answer by [@Henrik](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/73941/henrik-hansen) already suggests using a single regular expression to replace any characters in the group of brackets.

A mapping of characters seems an ideal solution in terms of performance. The mapping can be frozen using [`Object.freeze()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) to avoid alteration.

```
const BRACKET_MAPPING = Object.freeze({
  "(": ')',
  ")": '(',
  "{": '}',
  "}": '{',
  "[": ']',
  "]": '[',
});
const mapBracket = (bracket: string) => BRACKET_MAPPING[bracket];
const flipBracketsDirection = (str: string) => str.replace(/[\(\)\[\]\{\}]/g, mapBracket);
```

Comment: This looks clear and concise. Would it be possible to generate the regex from the keys of `BRACKET_MAPPING`?

Comment: yes- likely with the [Regexp constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Constructor)

Answer (score 6):

This is an [answer that I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62426116/15472) to the original question on StackOverflow. It does away with regular expressions entirely, and uses a similar case-statement to the one suggested in [@Henrik's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/244021/140466)

The original code performs 6 regular expression substitutions (which require 1 pass each), and fails on strings that contain the text `tempBracket` (as noted by @Kaiido in comments to the StackOverflow question).

This should be quicker because it makes a single pass, and requires no regular expressions at all. If all characters are ASCII, the `flip` function could be rewritten to use a look-up table, which would make it branch-free and potentially even faster.

```js
function flipBracketsDirection(str) {
  function flip(c) {
    switch (c) {
      case '(': return ')';
      case ')': return '(';
      case '[': return ']';
      case ']': return '[';
      case '{': return '}';
      case '}': return '{';
      default: return c;
    }
  }
  return Array.from(str).map(c => flip(c)).join('');
}    

// testcases
let test = (x) => console.log(flipBracketsDirection(x));
test('flip (it) anyway');
test(')hello(');
test('this has ]some text[');
test('flip }any{ brackets');
test('even with )))]multiple[((( brackets');
```

Comment: Can you also post this in [a new post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), with the tag [tag:rags-to-riches]? I have some thoughts .

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ you hereby have my permission to post my answer as a question to then answer it with your answer :-). I'll be happy to look at it (answer the comment so that I know to look).

Comment: I wouldn't really be able to (morally) post your code in a question because I wouldn't be able to answer "yes" to all the questions in the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page... (hint/protip: we can both gain more rep that way)

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ Then post the good code to get feedback for it! Regarding posting my code, the licensing is there (it is already on the site, and thus CC); and the moral aspect is also there (explicit permission in writing!). If you frame it as a performance competition, with regex vs split-join vs what-have-you, it would be actually quite interesting.

Comment: How bad is the performance hit of converting from string to array and back again, compared to regular expression replacement? I may be mistaken, but it seems like this would be more expensive than a simple regex

Comment: It seems like the regex wins out by 5-10% (https://jsperf.com/reverse-brackets)

Answer (score 1):

One for the fun of it

```js
const flipBrackets = BracketFlipper();
[ ')hello(', 
'this has ]some text[',
'flip }any{ brackets',
'even with )))]multiple[((( brackets',
'flip (it) anyway',
'>Pointy stuff<', 
'/slashed\\'].forEach(s => console.log(flipBrackets(s)));;

function BracketFlipper() {
  const bracks = "(),{},[],<>,\\\/".split(",");
  const brackets = [
    ...bracks, 
    ...bracks.reverse()
      .map(v => [...v].reverse().join("")) ]
    .reduce( (a, v) => ({...a, [v[0]]: v[1] }), {} );
  const re = new RegExp( `[${Object.keys(brackets).map(v => `\\${v}`).join("")}]`, "g" );
  return str => str.replace(re, a => brackets[a]);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```